# polygraph for https via proxy server

Tags: proxy, web-testing

Can anyone help me setup web polygraph for testing an HTTPS servers via proxy servers in middle
   linux machine:192.168.21.7
   proxy server :192.168.21.9
   https server : 192.168.21.11

Answer (score 1):

This link contains the needed information:
http://www.web-polygraph.org/docs/userman/simple.html

Basically polygraph has couple files which are bundled with it and use for testing.
The manual I gave you give example that uses polysrv but on different distributions you will probably have different names for the tool(on ubuntu it's polygraph-server and polygraph-client)

You need to set the listening service ip+port outgoing "robot" ip and then start it using command line.

Comment: my question was for https setup not http

Comment: have answered same on this post

Answer (score 0):

For https setup we will configure our pg file on server and client with **SslWrap** module.

Details of same can be found in http://www.web-polygraph.org/docs/reference/models/ssl.html